# SpringBoot: Could not transfer artifact

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I've got an issue with starting new project in IntelliJ :

- Maven build always terminates succesfully
- "Reload All Maven Projects" results in error
- can't import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication into main class

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>JavaTutorial</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Java Tutorial Course API</name>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
            <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        </properties>
    
    </project>
```

**NOTE:** I've tried to add `<dependencyManager>` into pom.xml but nothing changed at all.

Main class:

```
    package springbootstarter;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class CourseApiApp {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        }
    }
```

Error thrown when trying to Reload Maven project:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom
```

Any help would be appreciated. I was looking for any solutions but didn't succeed.

Comment: I've also tried what IntelliJ suggested: To run Maven import with -U flag, but only I got another error:
" Received fatal alert: protocol_version "

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy/firewall ? Furthermore using such an old spring boot version is intended?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a corporate laptop where I am behind proxy and spring version is related to our project. I just wanted to exercise to better understand SpringBoot while "working".

Comment: That it's wrong configuration in your settings.xml because you are not using the correct proxy/firewall setup or not using an internal repository manager instead of direct access to central which failed... If you like to understand Spring Boot better use recent versions https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

Comment: IDEs add complexity. You should always be able to build from the command line.  If you cannot do that, the error messages are often better.

Answer (score 0):

Logs looks like very clean, the project its trying to download the dependencies, however it's not able to.

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom
```

So, first check you connectivity to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
then verify if that dependency and specific version it's still there, because it's really old one. If so then try to force download dependencies, if you use maven, you could use:

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

**NOTE:**
Be aware that if you are behind a proxy, you must configure the proxy to be able to used by maven/gradle